# Implementing google play services in android

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am going along with the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started), and am getting there error `The method getIntentSender() is undefined for the type ConnectionResult` in the `onConnectionFailed` class.

**Full Code**

```
package com.alfalfa.thisthat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements
ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    /* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

    /* Client used to interact with Google APIs. */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /* A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents
     * us from starting further intents.
     */
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API, null)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
          if (!mIntentInProgress && result.hasResolution()) {
            try {
              mIntentInProgress = true;
              startIntentSenderForResult(result.getIntentSender(),
                  RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
              // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
              // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
              mIntentInProgress = false;
              mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
          }
        }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // We've resolved any connection errors.  mGoogleApiClient can be used to
        // access Google APIs on behalf of the user.
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
          mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
          if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
              mIntentInProgress = false;

                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
          }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
LogCat

```
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257): Process: com.alfalfa.thisthat, PID: 21257
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alfalfa.thisthat/com.alfalfa.thisthat.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.alfalfa.thisthat/com.alfalfa.thisthat.LoginActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.alfalfa.thisthat/com.alfalfa.thisthat.LoginActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at com.alfalfa.thisthat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-13 19:12:31.763: E/AndroidRuntime(21257):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As of today and Google Play SDK version 15, this has been replaced with

```
result.startResolutionForResult(this, // your activity
                                RC_SIGN_IN);
```

as per the updated [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#startResolutionForResult%28android.app.Activity,%20int%29).

Comment: If I changed that line to the above the LoginActivity class doesn't show any errors, but if I run the program with an intent from MainActivity to LoginActivity, the app force closes. Is there anything else I am doing incorrectly? Thanks.

Comment: Post your logcat if it is force closing

Comment: That error looks like you haven't declared one of your Activities in your Manifest and not related to Google Play Services.

Comment: thanks, that took away the error. I'm a toast saying "an internal error occurred" and the screen is flashing. not sure what that is. but ill save it for another question I guess. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Hope it helps you

```
result.getResolution().getIntentSender()
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.