# Internal error when signing in to Google+ in test app

Tags: android, google-play

At first, I had the same problem as this guy: [Implementing google play services in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767594/implementing-google-play-servics-android)

btw, I followed this tutorial including creating an oath 2.0 client ID: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started

I followed the solution there and it fixed the compilation error. However, now, when I try to actually have the user sign in it just says "Internal error."

Does anybody know if there is a good beginner tutorial for using google play or Google+ in apps?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem was resolved by following this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

then by visiting the Consent page under APIs & Auth in your developer control panel for the app. See screenshot here: http://picpaste.com/Consent_Screen.jpg