# Intergrate Google Plus

Tags: android, google-plus, integration

I am going along with the tutorial , and am getting error: The method getIntentSender() is undefined for the type ConnectionResult in the onConnectionFailed class. 
I want to integrate Google Plus on click of button,

Here is Full Code :

```
package com.example.demogoogleshare;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    Button signIn_button;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;
    PlusClient mPlusClient;

    /* Track whether the sign-in button has been clicked so that we know to resolve
     * all issues preventing sign-in without waiting.
     */
    private boolean mSignInClicked;

    /* Store the connection result from onConnectionFailed callbacks so that we can
     * resolve them when the user clicks sign-in.
     */
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
signIn_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signIn_button);
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.signIn_button) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "signIn", 1000).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!mIntentInProgress && result.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                startIntentSenderForResult(result.getIntentSender(), RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);

            }
            catch (SendIntentException e) {
                // The intent was canceled before it was sent. Return to the default
                // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // We've resolved any connection errors. mGoogleApiClient can be used to
        // access Google APIs on behalf of the user.
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing google play services in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767594/implementing-google-play-services-in-android)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Plus sharing from android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461345/google-plus-sharing-from-android-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 9000;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SHARE = 1000;
    private PlusClient mPlusClient;
    private PlusClient.Builder mPlusClientBuilder;
    private PlusShare.Builder mPlusShareBuilder;


//In your onCreate method write below code:

mPlusClientBuilder = new Builder(this, this, this);
        mPlusClientBuilder.setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN, Scopes.PROFILE);
        mPlusClient = mPlusClientBuilder.build();
mPlusClient.connect();

//OnActivityResult method:

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mPlusClient.disconnect();
            mPlusClient.connect();
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SHARE && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
            finish();
        }

    }

//OnConnectionFailed method:

@Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (result.hasResolution()) {
            // The user clicked the sign-in button already. Start to resolve
            // connection errors. Wait until onConnected() to dismiss the
            // connection dialog.
            try {
                result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                mPlusClient.disconnect();
                mPlusClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

//OnConnected method:

@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();

    }

//SignIn Button click:

btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (!mPlusClient.isConnected() && btnSignIn.getText().equals(getString(R.string.signin))) {
                    mPlusClient.connect();
                } else if (mPlusClient.isConnected() && btnSignIn.getText().equals(getString(R.string.signout))) {
                    mPlusClient.clearDefaultAccount();
                    mPlusClient.disconnect();




                }
            }
        });


// Share on google plus button click event:

btnShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mPlusClient.isConnected()) {

                    mPlusShareBuilder = new PlusShare.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    mPlusShareBuilder.setType("text/plain");
                    mPlusShareBuilder.setText(IN_SHARE_MESSAGE + IN_SHARE_LINK);
                    mPlusShareBuilder.setContentUrl(Uri.parse(IN_SHARE_LINK));

                    // Intent shareIntent =
                    // PlusShare.Builder.from(YOUR ACTIVITY.this).setText().setType("text/plain").setContent(Uri.parse("http://example.com/cheesecake/lemon"))
                    // .getIntent();
                    Intent shareIntent = mPlusShareBuilder.getIntent();
                    startActivityForResult(shareIntent, REQUEST_CODE_SHARE);
                } else {
                    //print failure message here
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: getting error here 
mPlusClientBuilder = new Builder(this, this, this);

Comment: @user3243147 you are missing mets-data tag in your manifest file, just add it first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59085/discussion-between-pratik-and-user3243147).

Comment: It is strongly suggested that you migrate away from PlusClient in favor of GoogleApiClient.  PlusClient will be removed in a future release (it's marked as deprecated already).  The migration is straightforward and offers a lot more flexibility.  More info at http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2014/02/migrating-from-plusclient-to.html

Comment: one more question want to ask ie
how can i fetch list of friends from google plus??
is there any api to fetch it??

Comment: @user3243147 yes you can fetch it from same api.